How is Hudson's theorem for the Wigner function proved?
Hudson's theorem tells us that a pure state has non-negative Wigner function iff it's Gaussian. This was originally proven in [Hudson 1974], and then generalised to multidimensional systems in [Soto and Claverie 1983].
Accessing these old papers is not however the easiest thing in the world.
Is there any more modern/easily accessible proof of this theorem? Alternatively, having the theorem's proof reproduced here would also make it much easier to access.

You are already aware of this, namely this,  and references therein, so what's the question? Do you appreciate the simple point/strategy involved?

@CosmasZachos Gross' paper doesn't replicate the proof of the original theorem. My point is essentially that it would be good to have the proof accessible without having to "fetch" and read 1970s papers. I couldn't find a textbook or other source reproducing it, but I'm not sure there isn't one. This Wiki page is actually the one that gets the closest to at least giving some more details. If there isn't, I think it'd be good to have the proof here

the original theorem is in fact a relatively simple result. Which is all the more reason to have the proof reproduced somewhere else as well, IMO. To be clear, I think of this question as more "what's the proof of Hudson's theorem" than "where can I find Hudson's theorem proof", because I don't think there is another source around (though I can't be sure). Which is why I didn't tag the question as resource-recommendations myself.

Linked.
